# multi colored edges python

Tags: python, graph, graphics

I'm testing an algorithm that finds a shortest path between two certain vertexes in graph and gives a list of vertexes after each turn (actually it gives three paths - one of them is a shortest path in this graph and two others are some kind of extra paths that are also important for us and are used for further shortest path calculations). On each turn the weights of graph edges change somehow so every turn we get a new triple of lists (paths). I would like to visualize the evolving of these paths by drawing a graph (this graph is actually a grid that represents a city, e.g. New York) and each kind of path would be represented with certain colour (so on each turn there would be a grid with three coloured paths). One more time - on every turn the paths will be different so the picture will change. What is the best way to represent it? And one more question - sometimes there would be edges that belong to two or maybe even three of these pathes and I'd like to show it, so it would be nice if there is an opportunity to colour this edge with two/three colours at once. It would be perfect if it was possible to make it look like two/three thinner edges put along together, but I could only find a situation where we draw several lines of different colour that are being put together consecutively (like that: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syx11.png)). Is there a way to make it the first way?

I'm sorry for being discursive but I've never dealt with graphics in Python and I desperately need help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the image in a GUI, it depends on the GUI toolkit that you want to use. In the `Tkinter` toolkit that comes with most Python distributions you could use the [`Canvas`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) widget. There are several tutorials online [[1]](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html), [[2]](http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_canvas.php). Most GUI toolkits have a similar functionality, but they can have different names.

If you want to save an image to a file, there are many graphics libraries you could use, depending on what kind of format you want to save it to.

- For example the [Python bindings to the Cairo library](http://cairographics.org/documentation/pycairo/3/reference/index.html#reference-index) can save a picture as PDF or SVG vector formats.
- The [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/) library on the other hand supports many bitmap formats.
- There are *many* others; [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/index.html), [agg](http://www.effbot.org/zone/pythondoc-aggdraw.htm), [gd](http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/gdmodule.html) are just some examples.